Psalm 6:9 - What is the difference between a plea and a prayer?
Psalm 6:9

The Lord has heard my plea;
the Lord accepts my prayer.

What is the difference between a plea and a prayer?

Hebrew poetry is based on parallels. I'd assume those lines are mostly synonymous.

I agree - this simply appears to be synthetic parallelism - thus, no difference is implied - rather, they are being treated as poetic synonyms.

Isn't a plea simply a specific part of the content of a prayer? E.g. "Give us this day our daily bread", is a plea within Jesus's example prayer, which also contains non-plea content.

A supplication and a prayer, though they may seem similar, have important nuances, especially in the Psalms and in the writings of David and Solomon.
In Psalm 6:9, David cries out to the Lord, and his supplication is heard. The difference between supplication and prayer lies in the intensity and nature of the request. A prayer is more general and can include praise, thanksgiving, and petitions. A supplication, however, is an urgent and deep plea, often related to situations of distress or extreme need.
This distinction is peculiar to David, as seen in Psalm 6:10 and Psalm 55:2, where he often makes supplications for deliverance, especially against enemies. In Psalm 55:12-14, it is clear that the supplication refers to an exceptional situation involving close enemies, those who have broken a peace covenant (Psalm 55:20) and revealed themselves as hypocrites and traitors (Psalm 55:21), described as "men of blood and deceit" (Psalm 55:23).
This practice of supplication also became part of Solomon’s prayers, especially in contexts of dedication and consecration. In 1 Kings 8:28, 38, 45, 49, 54 and 1 Kings 9:3, Solomon makes supplications to the Lord, asking for divine attention to specific cases, including war or calamity. Similarly, in 2 Chronicles 6:19, 29, 35, 39, Solomon offers supplications in critical moments, asking for God’s intervention.
Thus, supplication, particularly in the context of David and Solomon, was a form of intense and urgent prayer, especially in moments of conflict or betrayal.



Synonymous parallelism Synonymous parallelism occurs the most frequently and is the best known of the three categories. Synonymous parallelism, according to most interpreters, is the repetition of the same thought in two different phrases using two different, yet closely related, sets of words.
--
Longman, T., III. (1988). How to Read the Psalms (p. 99). IVP Academic; Inter-Varsity Press.


The two phrases in Psalm 6:9 form a synonymous parallel.  Thus, the type of prayer referred to is an heard plea and the type of plea is an accepted prayer.
